# Braid group B3 pure group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I will denote b1 as the twist of first two strands and b2 as the twist in the last two strands so that I have my two generators. When finding the kernelof B3 to S3 why is it wrong to list b1inverseb1 for the kernel?is it because by definition it is identity of braid group? What is an example of element in kernel then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that you're not trying to list elements in the kernel, since $b_1^{-1}b_1$ will definitely be in the kernel, since it's already trivial. However, if I were trying to provide *generators* for the kernel, I would not want to list things that are already trivial.  For instance, $b_1^2$ is not trivial in $B_3$, but it becomes trivial in $S_3$. This is possibly something you would want to see in your description of the kernel.

EDIT: In your title, you mentioned the pure braid group, which is by definition the kernel of the homomorphism you describe in the post. So yes, if you wanted to describe the pure braid group, you would need to give a list of things in the braid group that generate the entire kernel. Since something like $b_1^{-1}b_1$ is trivial, it doesn't make any sense to include in the list for the things that generate the kernel, since the trivial element is understood to be included in any list of generators for the kernel.

Comment: So b1^2 is in the kernel of this?so to find more do I keep making words of braid set that aren't trival and those would be the pure group? Do I have that right?

Comment: I understand now after a bit. Thanks.